# Creating RSS from email notifications

Tags: email, web-services, rss

I am signed up for a few forum threads (not this forum, but some other) in order to get notified of updates on my email. I want to generate from those email notifications new RSS feeds in order to read them via Feedly (Feedly supports both Windows and Android).

I've tried to use kill-the-newsletter.com, which creates a virtual email address and links it to a certain RSS, which I can then upload to Feedly.

At the same time I've also tried to set up filtered email forwarding from my main email box to the virtual address created by kill-the-newsletter.com.

The problem is that in order to initiate email forwarding my email provider first sends a note with a code to the virtual email address. I am supposed to confirm forwarding by validating the code in my main email box.

I expected that the note with the code would reach me via RSS feed in Feedly. However Feedly is processing new feeds real slow, so the note with the code never reaches me.

What can I do in order to be able to convert email notifications into RSS and read them via Feedly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, as this site is about recommending **software** – could you please **[edit]** your post and include relevant details on that (like what OS should be supported, what price is acceptable etc)? For reference, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Izzy, Feedly has an Android app and also can run via any browser (like Chrome) in Windows 10 or later. My question is rather about existing web services in general. What software those web services  run is not of high importance to me. I've actually managed to get solved the problem with kill-the-newsletter.com. The hint is to add new kill-the-newsletter's feed to your Feedly only after email forwarding is fully set up. But Feedly does exhibit some lag, so it may take a few attempts. I've also liased with the developers of kill-the-newsletter service and suggested an idea for improvement

Comment: Thanks Jimmy! Added the corresponding tag then to make that clearer. Good luck!